# Using <br /> tag within XML for XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am currently running into some trouble with an XML/XSLT to HTML conversion I am working on. 
In short, I want to use `<br />` tags within an XML tag, so that the HTML file after transformation will display a line break. After some tries I got that to work, however at the cost of some other functionality. Namely the ability to highlight parts.

First the dumped down XML file. So basically, there are several possible tags which all contain a first and last name. In this case I want the first and last name to be parsed on a separate line (hence the `<br />` tag). Furthermore in some instances a first or last name will need to be highlighted. In this case on line 3, last name "The Hand".

```
<swift_native>
<tag tag_code=":1:"><![CDATA[Jaco<br />Ronnie]]></tag>
<tag tag_code=":2:"><![CDATA[John<br />Doe]]></tag>
<tag tag_code=":2:"><![CDATA[Robbie<br />]]><highlight>The Hand</highlight></tag>
</swift_native>
```

So far, depending on the method I use within the XSLT I either am able to get the linebreaks correct or the highlighting. But not both: The following figure shows this.

[image: output]
Below you see the used XSLT file. Where you can see that using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` will make the highlighting work and `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` will let me use the `<br />` correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- HTML Layout definition -->
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="swift_native">

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="message_id"/>
            </title>
            <style type="text/css">
                #tbl1,#tbl2 {display:none;}
                #lnk1,#lnk2   {border:none;background:none;width:85px;}
                td {FONT-SIZE: 75%; MARGIN: 0px; COLOR: #000000;}
                td {FONT-FAMILY: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif}
                a {TEXT-DECORATION: none;}
                table.subtable {border-collapse:collapse;}
                table.subtable td {border:1px solid black;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table cellpadding="3" width="100%" class="subtable">
                <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                    <td colspan="3">Block4</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tag" />
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Variable definition -->

<xsl:template match="tag">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="@tag_code" />
            </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="highlight">
    <span style="background-color:yellow;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously, the question is: does someone know a way in which I can use both the `<br />` tag and the highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

`CDATA` is telling the processor to interpret the contents as plain text, not markup.  That's why `disable-output-escaping` is needed to prevent the `<br/>` from showing up as `&lt;br/&gt;`.

If you want to take advantage of `disable-output-escaping`, you'll have to break up the way that you select against the tag content.

Add a template

```
<xsl:template match="tag/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and change the `value-of` line to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="text()|*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. That clears things up, somewhat. One smalle remark. the `<highlight>` tag is actually outside the CDATA.

Comment: hello when <br/> tag occurred in string then disable-output-escaping="yes" its not working.

Answer (score 1):

One solution here is to use both:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="@tag_code" />
            </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag//text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="highlight">
    <span style="background-color:yellow;">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Note however that if you do this, you need to ensure that any text values within the `<tag>` nodes are properly escaped in the CDATA, and *doubly* escaped outside it, that is, rather than

```
<tag tag_code=":2:"><![CDATA[Robbie & Bobbie <br />]]><highlight> &amp; The Hand</highlight></tag>
```

You would need to have:

```
<tag tag_code=":2:"><![CDATA[Robbie &amp; Bobbie<br />]]><highlight> &amp;amp; The Hand</highlight></tag>
```

So this is probably not a great approach if the `<tag>` elements have any possibility of containing XML special characters.

If you can ensure that the text directly below the `<tag>` will *always* be in a CDATA and that anything in lower nodes (e.g. `<highlight>`s) won't, then it's mildly simpler.  You can replace the text matching template above with this one:

```
<xsl:template match="tag/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

And then you just need to ensure that the stuff in the CDATA is properly escaped, and that anything else is just valid XML.

Finally, if you have some control over your source data, you should consider abandoning the CDATA and just having the `<br />` right in the `<tag>`:

```
<tag tag_code=":2:">Robbie<br /><highlight>The Hand</highlight></tag>
```

Then you could use this XSL, which is much more robust than anything that uses `disable-output-escaping`:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="@tag_code" />
            </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag/@* | tag/node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="highlight">
    <span style="background-color:yellow;">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Happily, there's a simple solution too. Just add this line to your xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="br"><br/></xsl:template>
```

This way, there's no need to wrap the data into CDATA, but instead use the much more intuitive:

```
<tag tag_code=":1:">Jaco<br/>Ronnie</tag>
```

Likewise other common simple HTML tags may be included. Here's an example linking bold, italic, etc. to CSS styles, but a one-liner for each (like above) does work too:

```
<xsl:template match="i|b|u|strong">
    <span>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">html_<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

If you find yourself doing this often, copy them all to html.xsl and use `xsl:include` to use them when needed.

Comment: Sorry that won't work since the `<br />` in the input is CDATA. That's what @JLRishe was talking about in their answer. (Paragraph starting with "Finally" where abandoning the CDATA is discussed.)

Comment: Yep. No more need for CDATA, that's true. Use the much more intuitive `<tag tag_code=":1:">Jaco<br />Ronnie</tag>`

Comment: Be aware that most XSL processors will convert `<br />` to `<br></br>` which is the same in XML terms but not in HTML. HTML will read `<br></br>` as two `<br>`-tags cause a `<br>`-tag is a void tag in HTML and must not have a closing tag. In this case you have to use something like this: `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;br /&gt;</xsl:value-of>`

Answer (score -2):

if you want to make  in html is

all wath you need is to make in XLS  :

```
<br></br>
```

Comment: It is recommended, certainly in XHTML, to use the minimal self-closing syntax for empty elements, e.g. `<br />`, as the alternative syntax `<br></br>` allowed by XML can give uncertain results in user agents (https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2). In fact, the current version of HTML (v5) states that `<br>` alone can be used (with the end tag omitted - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-br-element) and no self-closing necessary, but obviously XML won't see this usage as well-formed.