# HTML within XML is not displayed properly in the output after conversion using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've an XML file generated as an output of a Java program. This contains some text in the form of html in which the tags are written with `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` respectively. I want to convert this xml to html where in the inner html is also processed. For example:

My xml snippet:

```
  <company>
        <companyEnhancement>
            Rank: -1&lt;/br&gt; Other Links&lt;/br&gt;http://www.gehealthcare.com/&lt;/br&gt;
        </companyEnhancement>
  </company>
```

And, my xslt stylesheet has this part to parse it:

```
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="companyEnhancement"/>     
     </td>
```

But the html output on the browser, has this data as it is within a table cell:

```
Rank: -1 </br> Other Links</br>http://www.gehealthcare.com/</br>
```

I read through the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567953/3409074), but I am not able to understand what exactly I should do in the stylesheet.

Please help me out. I am very new to xslt, so please excuse if it is a silly question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have HTML in there but `</br>` is not HTML syntax, that would be `<br>` or perhaps for XHTML `<br />`.

If you really have escaped HTML and want to output that then you can try

```
<xsl:value-of select="companyEnhancement" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

but that is only going to help if your XSLT processor serializes the result tree. Firefox for instance does not do that and does not support `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: Thanks alot, Martin. I did give a try with disable-output-escaping, but didn't workout. My browser is google chrome.

Comment: Thanks a tonne Martin.. Some magic happened, and the solution worked.